# how to work carousol this react bootstarp componenet?

Tags: javascript, react-bootstrap

here is my react bootstart carosol code.plese solve this problem

```
          <Carousel>
            <Carousel.Item>
                <img
                    className="d-block w-100" style={{ height: '500px' }}
                    src={img2}
                    alt="First slide"
                />
              
                </Carousel>``
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO: Please read how to ask questions - this one is too vague. What do you mean by saying "how to work"? Please also pay attention to your spelling. There are so many typos...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Carousel component slides images, which you provide. Of course it only make sense, if you provide at least two of them, not only one.

Also, in your code snippet you are missing the closing tag for Carousel.Item:

```
<Carousel>
    <Carousel.Item>
        <img
            className="d-block w-100" style={{ height: '500px' }}
            src={img1}
            alt="First slide"
        />
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
        <img
            className="d-block w-100" style={{ height: '500px' }}
            src={img2}
            alt="Second slide"
        />
    </Carousel.Item>
    ...
</Carousel>
```

If it's still not working, please make sure you are importing your images correctly. Do you see the image when you only paste following code?

```
<img
    className="d-block w-100" style={{ height: '500px' }}
    src={img1}
    alt="First slide"
/>
```

If not, then the problem is not the Carousel component, but your images.